# How to open a SAS file from SAS code through Batch processing?

Tags: batch-file, sas, sas-macro

I have a SAS macro program to test opening a file and outputting the total number of observations in the log. When I run it through SAS, I am able to output the number of observations in the SAS log (as intended). However, when I run the SAS program through a batch script, the file is not detected/can not be opened. What am I doing incorrectly?

See code for SAS program:

```
%macro syserrClass;

options symbolgen;

/* Define macro variables */
%let usernam = %sysget(pUserNam);
%let evSuffix = %sysget(pSuffix); /* Suffix of program name: eg. year 2018 */
%let evSeq = %sysget(pSeq);
%let evLib01 = %sysget(pLib01); /* SAS lib name for SAS data set */

*%let usernam = myusername;
*%let evSuffix = 2014;
*%let evSeq = 02;
*%let evLib01 = mor2014; /* SAS lib name for SAS data set */

%let filen03 = ije_mortality_&evSuffix.&evSeq._err; /* Input file */

LIBNAME &evLib01. v9 "C:\Users\&usernam.\Documents\My SAS Files\9.4\&evLib01.";

/* Open data set */
%let dsId1 = %sysfunc(open(&evLib01..&filen03.));

/* If the data set exists, get the number of observations */
%if &dsId1. %then %do;
 %let nobs1 = %sysfunc(attrn(&dsId1.,nobs));
 %let rc = %sysfunc(close(&dsId1.));
 %put &evLib01..&filen03. has &nobs1. observation(s).;
%end;
%else
%put Open for data set &evLib01..&filen03. failed - %sysfunc(sysmsg());

%mend;

/* Call macro */
%syserrClass;
```

See code for batch script (.cmd):

```
@echo off

setlocal

set "pUserNam=%username%"
set "pSuffix=%1"
set "pSeq=%2"
set "pLib01=%3"

set inPath01="C:\Users\%pUserNam%\Documents"
set inPath02="My SAS Files\9.4\"

set pInPath03=C:\Users\%pUserNam%\Documents\log
set pInPath05="C:\Program Files\SASHome\SASFoundation\9.4\sas.exe"
set pInPath06="C:\Program Files\SASHome\x86\SASFoundation\9.4\sas.exe"

rem set SAS exe path depending on existence of path
if exist %pInPath05% (set programname=%pInPath05%) else (set programname=%pInPath06%)

rem folder with output files - sas
set pLib02=mor%pSuffix%

rem Print summary of exceptions grouped by file name
set sasprogram="C:\Users\%username%\Documents\sascode\test_exceptrpt_macro01.sas"
%programname% -sysin %sasprogram% -log %pInPath03%\ije_mortality_exceptrpt01_%pSuffix%%pSeq%.txt -set pUserNam %pUserNam% -set pSuffix %pSuffix% -set pSeq %pSeq% -set pLib01 %pLib02%
echo SAS Program: %sasprogram%
if %ERRORLEVEL% GTR 1 (
 echo ERROR: Return code = %ERRORLEVEL%
 goto endproc
  ) else (echo NOTE: Return code = %ERRORLEVEL%)

:endproc
```

The main output that stands out in the log when I run through batch is:
`SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable DSID1 resolves to 0
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable EVLIB01 resolves to mor2014
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable FILEN03 resolves to ije_mortality_201402_err
Open for data set mor2014.ije_mortality_201402_err failed - ERROR: Libref MOR2014 is not assigned.`

However, when I switch up the SAS code to use the SAS interactive variables (see how I commented the second group of `%let` of `usernam`, `evSuffix`, `evSeq`, and `evLib01`), I get this in the log:
`SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable DSID1 resolves to 2
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable EVLIB01 resolves to mor2014
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable FILEN03 resolves to ije_mortality_201402_err
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable NOBS1 resolves to 5
mor2014.ije_mortality_201402_err has 5 observation(s).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on MPRINT so you can see the full text of the LIBNAME statement.  That will help you resolve the error.

```
Open for data set mor2014.ije_mortality_201402_err failed - ERROR: Libref MOR2014 is not assigned.
```

Comment: I added `options symbolgen mprint;` to my code. However, when I run the batch file, I still get the same error: `Open for data set mor2014.ije_mortality_201402_err failed - ERROR: Libref MOR2014 is not assigned.`

Comment: I was not suggesting that MPRINT would FIX the error, rather that you would see the MPRINTed LIBNAME statement and you would be able to tell if it is correct.  So show it.

Comment: Oh, okay. I am not sure how to utilize this information but this is what MPRINT shows in the log: `MPRINT(SYSERRCLASS):   * * * * LIBNAME &evLib01. v9 "C:\Users\&usernam.\Documents\My SAS 
Files\9.4\&evLib01.";`

Comment: Show the log in your question (edit the question) I did not expect the 4 asterisks preceding the  word LIBNAME.  Those appear to come from the %LETS you tried to comment out.  I don't think that worked like you think it did.  Get rid of those 4 *%let statement.  Or make them macro comments %*let=...;

Comment: Wow! Fixing the comments from `*%` to `%*` macro comment format was the solution! The 4 asterisks disappeared in the log and I got the same output through batch as running natively! Had been working on this for a few days...Thank you for pointing this out!